# Why adding facebook pixel code reduces the score on gtmetrix?

Tags: javascript, performance, facebook, plugins, gtmetrix

My score website on gtmetrix is A. When I add facebook pixel code, the scrore is B

Look at this :

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

I want to add the Facebook pixel code on my website, but I don't want it to reduce the score

Comment: Is the facebook pixel a script tag? If so, where is it placed in the html, head or body? If it's in the head it could be blocking the page content for long enough to bring your score down.

Comment: @Caleb Taylor Yes. I placed in the head. then where should I placed it? From the reference says to put it in the head tag

Comment: [Facebook Pixel slows down page load time by almost a full second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59838342/8234457), this poster suggest, which I would try as well, to place script inside body after content. Poster goes in more detail and other options

Comment: @Caleb Taylor  but are you sure if it is put on the body, it will work? in the link that you provide, there does not say put the script in the body

Comment: It will work because script tags can be run either in the head or body, what matters is whether you want to run before or after the page loads. Logic to determine color theme of webpage, place it in the <head> since we want to theme to set right away. Otherwise it's normal to place scripts inside <body>.

Comment: @Caleb Taylor  Yeah. But it's all the same. I had try to put it on body. The score on gtmetrix keeps going down

Comment: That's really strange, did you make sure to put the script last after all the content in the body?

`<body>
 ... content
<script>facebook pixel</script>
</body>
`

Comment: @Caleb Taylor Yeah of course

Comment: @Caleb Taylor I want to ask. I have a js file to store all javascript files. The name is combined.js. Can I save Facebook Pixec Code there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google tag manager for configuring facebook pixel.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your answer a little in textual form. Why would one use GTM? How to do this?